# Connecting power to switch

Tags: switch

[image][3-way switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DawD0.jpg)[image]I have a 2 gang box in wall. There were two 3-way switches installed. Removed one of those switches but kept the wires intact and capped off properly and power runs thru them to keep circuit for other switches in the room. 2nd  3-way switch still being used for another area not related to the removed 3-way. Wiring for existing 3-way completely separate from removed 3-way switch.

I want to install a single pole switch in same gang box where the 1st 3-way witch was located if possible to activate my fireplace log set which requires 110 volts. Is it possible to tap into the existing electricity from the 3-way switch to power up the new single pole switch for the fireplace?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box in question?

Comment: Yes. The box is congested. It appears the power running to this box is also powering the blower in the fireplace.  Pictures coming.

Comment: How do I post photos?

Comment: [edit] your question.  Right above the edit box will be Bold, Italic, Link, Quote, Something, and Add Image (Mountains and sun).

Comment: The valve on the fireplace system is an IPI valve (pilot light is only lit when turning fireplace on versus a Millivolt valve (pilot light on constantly). So I know I can’t run low voltage wiring.

Comment: Where does that black wire that's nutted off by itself go? Can you get us photos that show us more of what's behind the other switch in the box, for that matter, please?